# How can I determine whether an array is a prototype?

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

Checking is a value is an array is straight forward in JavaScript:

```
Array.isArray(value);
```

However, I need to distinguish between a value that is an array and a value that is andarray and also an array prototype. For instance:

```
Array.isArray([]); // true
Array.isArray(Object.getPrototypeOf([])); // true, but need false
```

Unfortunately the prototype of arrays is also type array, which is why `Array.isArray` returns true in this example.

If anyone knows how I can differentiate between the two (test for arrays, but **not** array prototypes) it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any Array instance can become a prototype of some other object at any time.

Comment: What difference between arrays and array prototypes forces you to distinguish between the two?

Comment: To put it another way, what problem are you trying to solve? This may be an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @ScottHunter I am classifying items in the prototype chain for development purposes and currently, with the method shown, the prototypes of arrays get misclassified as "regular" arrays.

Comment: That's the way prototypical inheritance works. Prototypes are an instance of their class, they're not special.

Comment: You could just test `if (obj == Object.getPrototypeOf([]))`

Comment: Prototypes of arrays *are* regular arrays. Being in a prototype chain does not change the nature of an object.

Comment: What problem are you really solving? This may be a case of [XY problem](http://www.xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Barmar @Pointy It is true that both are arrays. However, when I log `[]` and `Object.getPrototypeOf([])` I get different results (as expected) so an empty array is not the same object as the prototype of an empty array.

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli It is quite literally the example in the question: outputting different types and if they are "regular" or a prototype, it was easy for objects but with arrays I ran into this issue.

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli A JavaScript developer tool which also includes a prototype chain inspector.

Comment: @Ood "*when I log `[]` and `Object.getPrototypeOf([])` I get different results*" - that is a) because they inherit from different objects (`Array.prototype` and `Object.prototype` respectively) and b) because the latter has all the array methods as own properties while the former only has a `.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log([] instanceof Array) // true

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf([]) instanceof Array) // false
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note that using `instanceof` can fail in some fairly exotic circumstances, like objects that migrate between realms. The test checks to see if the object is an instance of the *local* Array constructor, but a migrated object (an Array) from another realm won't be. (One of the reasons `Array.isArray()` exists.)

Comment: @Pointy At first I thought about guarding it with `Array.isArray` but I couldn't think of an example that would require it, do you mind including one?